# Place an annotation onto a ggplot with TRUE and FALSE on the y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code does what I need for two simplified plots, but requires a magic number for the y-position instead of a calculation (commented out).

```
df1 <- data.frame(y=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),
                 x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
df2 <- data.frame(y=c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0),
                 x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

# yplace <- mean(as.numeric(levels(as.factor(df$y))))
yplace1 <- 1.5
yplace2 <- 0.5

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
    annotate("text", label="read me", x=mean(df1$x), y=yplace1)
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
    annotate("text", label="read me", x=mean(df2$x), y=yplace2)
```

[image: Simplified T/F plot] [image: Simplified 0/1 plot]

I am trying to write a generic function that will place an annotation at the center of ANY binomial scatterplot. The commented-out yplace assignment is the closest thing I've thought of, but it results in NA for TRUE/FALSE distributions. Is there a function or calculation I could use that would return 0.5 if the y vector is all 1s and 0s, and 1.5 for all TRUEs and FALSEs? I can't think of any other binomial distributions in common use, but handling any case where the y vector contains two factors would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `getYplace` does what you want. It checks if vector is TRUE/FALSE and returns `1.5` or if it's numeric then returns mean between two numbers.

```
getYplace <- function(Y) {
    if (is.numeric(Y)) {
        res <- mean(unique(Y))
    } else {
        res <- 1.5
    }
    return(res)
}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    annotate("text", label = "read me", x = mean(df1$x), y = getYplace(df1$y))

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    annotate("text", label = "read me", x = mean(df2$x), y = getYplace(df2$y))
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I found is.logical() and unique() to be very useful, so I tweaked your conditional to cover all cases, not just logicals.

Comment: @mightypile Oh, I see, happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe determining the y value for the annotation will work as mentioned with the mean of the factors as long as they are numeric. If they are not numeric, factors will be assigned counting numbers, 1,2,3,...

So the following works, probably for all two-factor vectors, but doesn't strike me as very elegant and calculates the ugly mean twice.

```
yplace1 = if(is.na(mean(as.numeric(levels(as.factor(df1$y))))))
    1.5
else
    mean(as.numeric(levels(as.factor(df1$y))))
```